# Which API building practice is better?

Tags: java, rest, api, web-api, vue.js

Im working on a ERP product, In which backend logics are to be APIs. Right now I have around
80 Tables.

Proposal 1: Creating CRUD APIs for all tables and manipulation of data to be handled in front End.

Proposal 2: Creating CRUD APIs with few Buffer APIs for Data manipulation (Business logics or joining multiple table) and sending the final json to front end?

Front End: Vue.js (Most likely)

Which proposal is better? Or If there is any better solutions I would love to listen.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: If your ERP product can be used outside of a restricted LAN but through the internet, then in proposal 1 you *will* get requests that are not valid according to the business rules and you cannot do anything about that because the business rules are not known at the server.

Comment: Proposal 3: create APIs that do the things the front-end needs them to do. Is it a CRUD app?

Answer (score 0):

Having a large API to interface with the front end will guarantee that you have a large amount of business logic within a SPA framework. Having a layered amount distributed approach would be much better. If you have a business logic layer, that would solve a large code base in the view portion. There is a lot here that needs to be thought about. A post with minimal knowledge of the application in question couldn't possibly answer your questions.